# Attempting to find average and max in an array in Java then print

Tags: java, arrays, printing, max, average

New to coding and I'm working on my homework. Can someone help me try to figure this out? My homework assignment is to create separate methods to calculate the average, find the maximum, and then print those out. I'm working on the average now but I'm getting stuck. It's saying my return values is outside the method. Can someone please help? Thanks. Here's my code so far

```
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myIntegers = getIntegers[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < myIntegers.length; i++) {
    }
    System.out.println("The average of your whole numbers is " + getAverage(myIntegers));
}

public static int[] getIntegers[];

{
    System.out.println("Enter three whole numbers.\r");
    int[] values = new int[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    return values;
}

public static double getAverage(int[] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    return (double) sum / (double) array.length;
}
```

}

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Square brackets `[]` in Java are **only** used for indicating arrays like `int[]` or referencing a certain index in some array `values[3]`. Take a look at your `getIntegers` method, it should be `getIntegers() { ... }`, no square brackets.

Comment: Thank you so much, Zabuza. That did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of getIntegers should use parenthesis, not square brackets.  And the call to that method should just have parenthesis, not "[2]".

Comment: Thank you kindly. I was able to fix the issue now